# sort on two columns

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with site visits with the following columns:

```
timestamp
host
url
```

I would like to see the last few (say 200) visits but at the same time group visits of the same host together (to see the sequence of pages he/she visits).

If I do:

```
... SORT BY timestamp DESC, host
```

I get hosts mixed up if several visitors are online at the same time

If I do:

```
... SORT BY host, timestamp DESC
```

I do not get the latest visits (just the latest visits from each host)

I would like to see e.g.

```
9:01 | a.com | /index
9:05 | a.com | /interesting
9:07 | a.com | /contact
9:02 | b.com | /index
9:03 | b.com | /product-a
9:08 | b.com | /thanks-for-buying
```

Is that possible in Mysql or should I further process the result in php?

Comment: Please explain the columns and the table content, along with the complete query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above pointed my in the right direction, thanks. This one works. The LIMIT 1000 is to reduce the query from almost 3 minutes to 7 seconds (40000 records).

```
SELECT v1.stamp, v1.host FROM visits AS v1 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(date) AS firstVisit, host
              FROM visitor AS v2 
              GROUP BY v2.host
              ORDER BY firstVisit DESC
              LIMIT 1000) AS j
       ON v1.host=j.host 
       ORDER BY firstVisit DESC, v1.host, v1.date DESC
       LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select *, MAX(timestamp_col) as lastVisit from site_table

GROUP BY HOSTS order by lastVisit desc
```

Comment: This got me on the right track (see answer). What lacks is a join with the full table (and I need MIN instead of MAX)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `ORDER BY` followed by `LIMIT` and then another `ORDER BY`, so you have to use a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
    FROM visits
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 200
) visits2
ORDER BY host
```

Comment: In practice this accomplishes what I want (to have the recent visits grouped per host). What I wanted additionally was to order the blocks of hosts by their first visit's timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit the result if you want the last 200

```
  SORT BY timestamp DESC, host LIMIT 0, 200
```

And if you dont the same visitor to show up again , use

```
SELECT DISTINCT visitor FROM ....
```

Comment: With distinct how you will get the last visit of that particular user

Comment: I do want multiple page views of the same visitor but I want to see them grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible make normal in one query. You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS t1 
WHERE t1.timestamp_col >= (SELECT MIN(tstamp) 
    FROM (SELECT t2.timestamp_col 
        FROM tables AS t2 
        WHERE t2.host = t1.host 
        ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC 
        LIMIT 200
    )
)
```

I don't test this crazy code... But I hope it give you way :)

Comment: me neither... Some kind of join was needed however, see my answer below